# Sending email programmatically from android

Tags: java, android, email

i am trying to send an email programmatically from an android phone. I am referring to this post [How To Send Email Without User Interaction Using SMTP](http://mobiledevtuts.com/android/android-sdk-smtp-email-tutorial/)

I followed the steps and completed it. The problem is that application is not running. Please refer to my codes if there are errors or suggest me with solution to tackle this problem. Thanks.

Code for Mail.java

```html
package com.example.sendemailfromandroid;


import java.util.Date; 
import java.util.Properties; 
import javax.activation.CommandMap; 
import javax.activation.DataHandler; 
import javax.activation.DataSource; 
import javax.activation.FileDataSource; 
import javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap; 
import javax.mail.BodyPart; 
import javax.mail.Multipart; 
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication; 
import javax.mail.Session; 
import javax.mail.Transport; 
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress; 
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart; 
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage; 
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart; 


public class Mail extends javax.mail.Authenticator { 
 private String _user; 
 private String _pass; 

 private String[] _to; 
 private String _from; 

 private String _port; 
 private String _sport; 

 private String _host; 

 private String _subject; 
 private String _body; 

 private boolean _auth; 

 private boolean _debuggable; 

 private Multipart _multipart; 


 public Mail() { 
  _host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // default smtp server 
  _port = "465"; // default smtp port 
  _sport = "465"; // default socketfactory port 

  _user = ""; // username 
  _pass = ""; // password 
  _from = ""; // email sent from 
  _subject = ""; // email subject 
  _body = ""; // email body 

  _debuggable = false; // debug mode on or off - default off 
  _auth = true; // smtp authentication - default on 

  _multipart = new MimeMultipart(); 

  // There is something wrong with MailCap, javamail can not find a handler for the multipart/mixed part, so this bit needs to be added. 
  MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap(); 
  mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html"); 
  mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml"); 
  mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain"); 
  mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed"); 
  mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822"); 
  CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc); 
 }
 

 public Mail(String user, String pass) { 
  this(); 

  _user = user; 
  _pass = pass; 
 } 

 public boolean send() throws Exception { 
  Properties props = _setProperties(); 

  if(!_user.equals("") && !_pass.equals("") && _to.length > 0 && !_from.equals("") && !_subject.equals("") && !_body.equals("")) { 
   Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this); 

   MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session); 

   msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_from)); 

   InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[_to.length]; 
   for (int i = 0; i < _to.length; i++) { 
    addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(_to[i]); 
   } 
   msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo); 

   msg.setSubject(_subject); 
   msg.setSentDate(new Date()); 

   // setup message body 
   BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
   messageBodyPart.setText(_body); 
   _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 

   // Put parts in message 
   msg.setContent(_multipart); 

   // send email 
   Transport.send(msg); 

   return true; 
  } else { 
   return false; 
  } 
 } 

 public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception { 
  BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
  DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename); 
  messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source)); 
  messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename); 

  _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 
 } 

 @Override 
 public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() { 
  return new PasswordAuthentication(_user, _pass); 
 } 

 private Properties _setProperties() { 
  Properties props = new Properties(); 

  props.put("mail.smtp.host", _host); 

  if(_debuggable) { 
   props.put("mail.debug", "true"); 
  } 

  if(_auth) { 
   props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); 
  } 

  props.put("mail.smtp.port", _port); 
  props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", _sport); 
  props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"); 
  props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false"); 

  return props; 
 } 

 // the getters and setters 
 public String getBody() { 
  return _body; 
 } 

 public void setBody(String _body) { 
  this._body = _body; 
 } 

 public void setTo(String[] toArr) {
  this._to = toArr;
 }

 public void setFrom(String string) {
  this._from = string;
 }

 public void setSubject(String string) {
  this._subject = string;
 }

 // more of the getters and setters ….. 
}
```

Code for Main activity:

```html
package com.example.sendemailfromandroid;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;
 
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 private Mail m;
 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override 
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
  m = new Mail("xxxxxxx@gmail.com", "xxxxxxxxx"); 
 }
 
 public void sendEmail(View view){
  String[] toArr = {"zzzzzzzz@gmail.com"}; // This is an array, you can add more emails, just separate them with a coma
  m.setTo(toArr); // load array to setTo function
  m.setFrom("xxxxxxx@gmail.com"); // who is sending the email 
  m.setSubject("subject"); 
  m.setBody("your message goes here"); 
 
  try { 
   //m.addAttachment("/sdcard/myPicture.jpg");  // path to file you want to attach
   if(m.send()) { 
    // success
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Email was sent successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
   } else { 
    // failure
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Email was not sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
   } 
  } catch(Exception e) { 
   // some other problem
   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "There was a problem sending the email.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
  } 
 
 }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```html
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.sendemailfromandroid.MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Send Mail"
        android:onClick="sendEmail" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

logotcat:

```html
01-28 17:33:11.821: W/ResourcesManager(15519): getTopLevelResources: com.example.sendemailfromandroid for user  0
01-28 17:33:11.821: I/InjectionManager(15519): Inside getClassLibPath + mLibMap{0=, 1=}
01-28 17:33:11.831: I/InjectionManager(15519): Inside getClassLibPath caller 
01-28 17:33:11.831: D/InjectionManager(15519): InjectionManager
01-28 17:33:11.831: D/InjectionManager(15519): fillFeatureStoreMap com.example.sendemailfromandroid
01-28 17:33:11.831: I/InjectionManager(15519): Constructor com.example.sendemailfromandroid, Feature store :{}
01-28 17:33:11.831: I/InjectionManager(15519): featureStore :{}
01-28 17:33:11.841: I/art(15519): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.example.sendemailfromandroid.Mail>
01-28 17:33:11.841: I/art(15519): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.example.sendemailfromandroid.Mail>
01-28 17:33:11.841: I/art(15519): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.example.sendemailfromandroid.Mail>
01-28 17:33:11.841: I/art(15519): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.example.sendemailfromandroid.Mail>
01-28 17:33:11.841: I/art(15519): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.example.sendemailfromandroid.Mail>
01-28 17:33:11.841: I/art(15519): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.example.sendemailfromandroid.Mail>
01-28 17:33:11.841: I/art(15519): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.example.sendemailfromandroid.Mail>
01-28 17:33:11.841: I/art(15519): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.example.sendemailfromandroid.Mail>
01-28 17:33:11.841: W/ResourcesManager(15519): getTopLevelResources: com.example.sendemailfromandroid for user  0
01-28 17:33:11.841: W/ResourcesManager(15519): getTopLevelResources: com.example.sendemailfromandroid for user  0
01-28 17:33:11.841: D/DisplayManager(15519): DisplayManager()
01-28 17:33:11.881: D/PhoneWindow(15519): *FMB* installDecor mIsFloating : false
01-28 17:33:11.881: D/PhoneWindow(15519): *FMB* installDecor flags : 8454400
01-28 17:33:11.891: I/art(15519): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.example.sendemailfromandroid.Mail>
01-28 17:33:11.891: D/AndroidRuntime(15519): Shutting down VM
01-28 17:33:11.891: E/AndroidRuntime(15519): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-28 17:33:11.891: E/AndroidRuntime(15519): Process: com.example.sendemailfromandroid, PID: 15519
01-28 17:33:11.891: E/AndroidRuntime(15519): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.sendemailfromandroid.Mail
01-28 17:33:11.891: E/AndroidRuntime(15519):  at com.example.sendemailfromandroid.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
01-28 17:33:11.891: E/AndroidRuntime(15519):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6178)
01-28 17:33:11.891: E/AndroidRuntime(15519):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
01-28 17:33:11.891: E/AndroidRuntime(15519):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2648)
01-28 17:33:11.891: E/AndroidRuntime(15519):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2769)
01-28 17:33:11.891: E/AndroidRuntime(15519):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
01-28 17:33:11.891: E/AndroidRuntime(15519):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1430)
01-28 17:33:11.891: E/AndroidRuntime(15519):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-28 17:33:11.891: E/AndroidRuntime(15519):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
01-28 17:33:11.891: E/AndroidRuntime(15519):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910)
01-28 17:33:11.891: E/AndroidRuntime(15519):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-28 17:33:11.891: E/AndroidRuntime(15519):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
01-28 17:33:11.891: E/AndroidRuntime(15519):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
01-28 17:33:11.891: E/AndroidRuntime(15519):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
01-28 17:33:13.241: I/Process(15519): Sending signal. PID: 15519 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Code snippets are for javascript

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
            "mailto","abc@gmail.com", null));
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Body");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));
```

For send to more then 1 address

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, addresses); // String[] addresses
```

Comment: OP wants to send an email without any user interaction. It won't be possible  with your solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the error: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.sendemailfromandroid.Mail` it's saying it can't find, and there for, can't use your `Mail` class in your `onCreate()`.

From the `Java` documentation on `NoClassDefFoundError`:

> Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine or a ClassLoader instance tries to load in the definition of a class (as part of a normal method call or as part of creating a new instance using the new expression) and no definition of the class could be found.
>   The searched-for class definition existed when the currently executing class was compiled, but the definition can no longer be found.

I would check your package structure to make sure your imports are correct. If your files are located in the same folder and you are still having this issue, try compiling you `Mail` class separately and see if there are any errors.